# Video not showing in Safari

Tags: safari, html5-video

I have a video which plays sound but does not display the video on macOS Safari. I have tried the following solutions but didn't work:

- I have tried playing around with combinations of attributes: autoplay muted playsinline loop;
- I have tried converting and changing the extension to .mov;
- I have tried switching between setting src in `<video>` tag and moving it inside with `<source>` tag;
- I have tried settings src both absolute path and relative path; the website is https

The video plays:

- in the original website,
- in any other desktop browser;
- if I open it in a separate tab;
- in IOS Safari;

In the Safari dev tools console it says: "An error appeared attempting to open the resource".

This is the current html code used to show the video:

```
<video controls muted playsinline loop preload="metadata">
 <source src="https://sistemecreative.ro/demo-istoma/assets/Triaj2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 <p>Your browser does not support HTML5 video.</p>
<video>
```

The video in question can be found at:
https://sistemecreative.ro/demo-istoma/

The current live website: https://istoma.ro/
In the live website it's the first video.

Comment: What is your video format (MP4? MOV? 3GP?) and what is the audio codec (MP3? AAC?). Get a tool called **MediaInfo** if you do not know. Maybe your audio type is not supported outside of Apple products.

Comment: A [mcve] would be useful

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comments, I have updated my question with code and links to pages.

Comment: no idea why, but toggling the `display: flex;` rule on `.is-flex-center` off and back on in dev tools makes it visible

Comment: @misterben thanks for you insight, at the moment I figured out a workaround...sadly, a bit rough around the edges.
When the page loads I:
1. check if it's Safari browser;
2. set the display to block and then back to flex;